# How can I get picked image from ios camera roll exact URI path?

Tags: ios, react-native, image-processing, uri

I am stuck today at ios image uri path

It is giving me path like this.and it is uploading to server as it is so i can't load these images in my view. Please help me anyone

assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=CE542E92-B1FF-42DC-BD89-D61BB70EB4BF&ext=PNG

But i want the path something like this

file:///Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/########-####-####-####-############/data/Containers/Data/Application/########-####-####-####-############/Documents/########-####-####-####-############.png

Here is the link of a similar unanswered question - [After Image Uploading, image uri is null for iOS alone in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056811/after-image-uploading-image-uri-is-null-for-ios-alone-in-react-native#)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). It has a `copyAssetsFileIOS` method which generates absolute path from an asset. The following sample copies the photo to the temp  directory and gets its path:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

getAbsolutePath = async (assetPath) => {
    const destination = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.png`;
    try {
      let absolutePath = await RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(assetPath, destination, 0, 0);
      console.log(absolutePath)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    } 
}
```